# Insert one array value to a mysql insert statement

Tags: php

People enter values into a form and on one entry of the form I have multiple values.

Eg: 
One Entry for Name
 and Multiple entries for hobbies.

I could enter into the db by running a for loop but then that would be multiple entries for the same name for each different hobby.

How can I enter one name and all hobbies with 'space' into one DB field 'TWIG'. I could use arrays but it shows up as ARRAY but then its back to FOR loop.

```
for ($t=0; $t<=$_POST['tc']-1; $t++) { 
    echo "<BR> ts:".$_POST[$t]."<BR>"; 
    $ths[]=$_POST[$t];
}
print_r ($ths);

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO quest(cnos, dte, twig)
    VALUES(:q, :d, :t )");
$statement->execute(array(
    ":q" => htmlspecialchars ($_POST['iht']),
    ":d" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'],
    ":t"=> $ths
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function for this as follows:

```
":t"=> implode(" ", $ths);
```

Comment: This is just like buffering on youtube!

Comment: @X10nD your database schema isn't good. you will have too much headaches later on.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to implode your hobbies / concatinate your string into one...

```
for ($t=0; $t<=$_POST['tc']-1; $t++) {
    $ths = $_POST[$t] . " "; //Concatinate string, do no use array!
}

//Cut off last character " " to avoid ugly space at the end:
$ths = substr($ths, 0, strlen($ths) - 1);
```

However a more clean solution is to make a more clear database structure if you want for atomic values.

This is an 1:n relation (Each of your entries in table A relates to n instances in table B).

Here is an example that can be adapted into your schema very easy:

```
Table User(id[PK], name, age);

Table User_Hobbies: (user_id, hobby_descr);

--

INSERT INTO User(2, "Chris", 19);

INSERT INTO USER_User_Hobbies(2, "videogames");
INSERT INTO USER_User_Hobbies(2, "music");


--

Example query:

SELECT u.name, u.age, GROUP_CONCAT(uh.hobby_descr) AS hobbies
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN User_Hobbies uh ON u.id = uh.user_id
WHERE u.id = 123 /*Where is optional, if you want to filter for a specific user*/
GROUP BY u.id;

Possible result:
| name  | age  | hobbies                      | 
 chris    18   videogames, music
 steve    22   computer, programming, php
```

Comment: @itachi That would require a loop query to display values in a table.  Can you do a join of two tables in a mysql/php? steini

Comment: @X10nD yup it will need a loop. what's the harm in that? and yes, you'l need to join too.

Comment: @itachi Running a loop on multiple queries is a load.  Can you check to see if you can join two mysql statements in PHP?

Comment: Yes you can use a join query combined with group_concat and get all results with a single query. I will write an example...

Comment: @X10nD in `insert`, it will be batch insert so there will be only _one_ sql statement, __no loop__. for retrieving, again just one query, no loop.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl (col1,col2,col3) VALUES(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i);` instead running 3 similiar queries, barch insert is just one query where it creates multiple entries with respective values.

Comment: Added one sample query

Comment: @itachi let me take a look

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if I understand your question right, but if you want to insert an array as a comma-seperated string (or separated by whatever), why don't use the php implode function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php

For example:

```
$myHobbies = array("football", "basketball", "running");
$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO quest(cnos, dte, twig)
    VALUES(:q, :d, :t )");
$statement->execute(array(
    ":q" => htmlspecialchars ($_POST['iht']),
    ":d" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'],
    ":t"=> implode(" ", $myHobbies)
));
```

I think to use comma's or semicolons as separator, is better than whitespaces, since some of the hobbies could consists of two words (for example "pc gaming").

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of using comma instead of space

Answer (score 0):

I think that better solution is to use json_encode and not implode, since it provides more robust structure.

```
":t" => json_encode($myHobbies)
```

Comment: how does it provide better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join function to store multiple value in same field in database may be it will works:-

```
   ":t"=>join(",", $ths);//if you want ,(coma) between two string 

         or 
   ":t"=>join(" ", $ths);//if you want space between two string
```